# Google Sheets: string to columns and rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a string separated by commas. Easily with split formula I can have each data in separated cells but all the data are in one single row. I need to transform data from this format:

[image]

to this format:

[image]

where the value in the column F is associated to only one row. So it means that one and only one block of the original string is longer than the others. Following the above screenshots:

1st block of the string:
fubles.com/matches/2655533,Atletico Saraitu,Edoardo Pallavicini,7.38,6,

7th block of the string:
fubles.com/matches/2655533,Atletico Saraitu,Andrea Cissello,7.55,7,Yes,

Is there anyone that can help me to build the right formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 parts - first to separate the different rows - then run split again on the rows after you save the values - use substitute or regexreplace to add in a different delimiter, i prefer to use the semicolon:

```
=transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"fubles",";fubles"),";"))
```

[image]

OR

```
=transpose(split(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"fubles",";fubles"),";"))
```

[image]

They literally do the exact same thing, but essentially you are adding the semicolon in from of your starting string, then you split by that delimiter, the transpose to stack the rows.

You should then COPY and `PASTE VALUES`  to flatten the data - then run your split by comma on all those rows.