# How to transpose rows into columns of contact details without mixing them up? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set of contact details where the emails and their names are scattered in rows, I would like to list them in 2 nice columns. I've tried using "paste special" and use this code below, but none of them worked.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried this code, but it only applies to one row, whereas I want to apply it to all rows and columns.

```
=transpose(A2:R2)
```

and

```
=transpose (A2:R300)
```

Both don't work. I hope somebody can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks that you are using the wrong terms so you are using the wrong functions. You have a cell with data separated with spaces and break lines and you want to have each email and name on it's own cell, having emails on one column and names on the next column, right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are using the wrong terms so you are using the wrong functions.

Apparently you have a cell with data separated by spaces and break lines and you want to have each email and name on it's own cell, having emails on one column and names on the next column.

One way to achieve that, first replace the separating spaces by using a character like `|` and the break lines by another different character like `$`.

Note: Some people use Unicode characters that are very unlikely to appear like `♦`, `❤`.

To do the above for break lines you could use FIND and REPLACE (Ctrl + H) or function formulas like REGEXREPLACE, SUBSTITUTE, and maybe others. As there are spaces used both as word separators and values separators, FIND and REPLACE can't be used easily. For a single cell, maybe the easier way is to insert the name/email separator manually.

Then separate the cell data. To do this you could use a formula function like SPLIT or Data > Separate values into columns.

Another way is by using Google Apps Script and JavaScript string handling methods but basically the algorithm is the same.

Related

- [How to split this complex string into 3 columns and 50 rows using Google sheet script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47499745/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script: Create new rows for cells that contain commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54680174/1595451)
- [Google Sheets: string to columns and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40227592/1595451)